# How do I retrieve multiple row node data from an html table in XPATH?

Tags: xpath, domxpath

Sometime during the dark ages a script was built that outputs the following html..

```
...
<TABLE BORDER=0 FRAME=ALL_FRAMES RULES=ALL_RULES ALIGN=CENTER BGCOLOR="ffffe5">
<CAPTION ALIGN=TOP>
<FONT  COLOR=009594 SIZE=-1><B>Access Information</B></FONT>
</CAPTION>
<TR>
<TD ALIGN=RIGHT VALIGN=MIDDLE>
<FONT  COLOR=black SIZE=-1><B>Access Circuit(s):</B></FONT>
</TD>
<TD ALIGN=LEFT VALIGN=MIDDLE>
**DATA TO COLLECT 111**
</TD>
<TD ALIGN=RIGHT VALIGN=MIDDLE>
<FONT  COLOR=black SIZE=-1><B>Other Circuit(s):</B></FONT>
</TD>
<TD ALIGN=LEFT VALIGN=MIDDLE>
&nbsp
</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD ALIGN=RIGHT VALIGN=MIDDLE>
&nbsp
</TD>
<TD ALIGN=LEFT VALIGN=MIDDLE>
**DATA TO COLLECT AAA**
</TD>
<TD ALIGN=RIGHT VALIGN=MIDDLE>
&nbsp
</TD>
<TD ALIGN=LEFT VALIGN=MIDDLE>
&nbsp
</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD ALIGN=RIGHT VALIGN=MIDDLE>
&nbsp
</TD>
<TD ALIGN=LEFT VALIGN=MIDDLE>
**DATA TO COLLECT BBB**
</TD>
<TD ALIGN=RIGHT VALIGN=MIDDLE>
&nbsp
</TD>
<TD ALIGN=LEFT VALIGN=MIDDLE>
&nbsp
</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD ALIGN=RIGHT VALIGN=MIDDLE>
&nbsp
</TD>
<TD ALIGN=LEFT VALIGN=MIDDLE>
**DATA TO COLLECT CCC**
</TD>
<TD ALIGN=RIGHT VALIGN=MIDDLE>
&nbsp
</TD>
<TD ALIGN=LEFT VALIGN=MIDDLE>
&nbsp
</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD ALIGN=RIGHT VALIGN=MIDDLE>
<FONT  COLOR=black SIZE=-1><B>Customer:</B></FONT>
</TD>
...
```

*Sorry, I would show you the table layout but I don't know how without `<table>` on SO*

How can I use XPATH (in PHP) to collect only each `DATA TO COLLECT` section? So far I've been able to retrieve the first row with `//*[*='Access Circuit(s):']/following-sibling::td[1]`.

Things to note:

- This is only a small section of a large document.
- I cannot change the scripts output.
- I wont know how many rows there will be (figure 0 to 6).
- The data should be expected to always be in the same "column".
- I may only have XPATH version 1. But version 2 answers are still welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression I came up with is this:

```
//TR[(.//B[.='Access Circuit(s):']) or ((./preceding-sibling::TR//B[.='Access Circuit(s):']) and (./following-sibling::TR//B[.='Customer:']))]//TD[2]
```

returns

```
<TD ALIGN="LEFT" VALIGN="MIDDLE">**DATA TO COLLECT 111**</TD>
<TD ALIGN="LEFT" VALIGN="MIDDLE">**DATA TO COLLECT AAA**</TD>
<TD ALIGN="LEFT" VALIGN="MIDDLE">**DATA TO COLLECT BBB**</TD>
<TD ALIGN="LEFT" VALIGN="MIDDLE">**DATA TO COLLECT CCC**</TD>
```

It uses the knowledge that the first row contains `Access Circuit(s):` and the first uncollected row contains `Customer:`. If you can't be sure of either one of those, then I think it can't be done with a single XPath expression.

```
Step-by-step
1. //TR[
2.     (.//B[.="Access Circuit(s):"])
3.     or (     (./preceding-sibling::TR//B[.="Access Circuit(s):"])
4.          and (./following-sibling::TR//B[.="Customer:"]) )
5.     ]//TD[2]

Means
1. all TR nodes
2. that either contain "Access Circuit(s):"
3. or
    - (3.) are positioned after "Access Circuit(s):"
    - (4.) and are positioned before "Customer:"
5. all TD nodes that are the second TD of their parents
```

Comment: Oops, That first node wasn't labeled correctly and should be collected like the others.  Also this is a small section of a very large document that has no identifying labels other than table data.  I should have been more clear.  I've edited my source.

Comment: ...that means that the first expression works well, doesn't it?

Comment: ...except that it will return many other unwanted second `td` children nodes in the document before and after the "Access Circuit" section.

Comment: This logic looks exactly like what I am working towards.  However, `(.//B[.="Access Circuit(s):"])` is returning the second `td` children of the whole doc while `((./preceding-sibling::TR//B[.="Access Circuit(s):"]) and (./following-sibling::TR//B[.="Customer:"]))` returns nothing.  I'm just not versed well enough in XPATH to know how to tweak it.

Comment: What xpath version is this written for?

Comment: That is most surely the answer then.

Comment: @Isius And is it working? If not, try to modify your example a bit to show the problem. For instance, are there more "Customer:" cells in your original file?

Comment: It took me most of the day to figure out that the data I was using was different than the data I expected. (facepalm) Once I got the two aligned it worked quite well. I ended up using `//tr[(./td/font/b[.="Access Circuit(s):"]) or ((./preceding-sibling::tr/td/font/b[.="Access Circuit(s):"]) and (./following-sibling::tr/td/font/b[.="Customer:"]))]/td[2]`.  Also, I discovered that one may use $x('query') in Chrome's console to test, and that case matters.  +1 for walking me through and putting in the extra effort.